# How to postion jQuery footer at the bottom of each screen

Tags: jquery, css, cordova

I'm building a mobile app in jQuery and phonegap.

For some reason the `data-role="footer"` does not sit at the bottom of the tablet screens.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use **`data-position="fixed"`** attribute:

```
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks thats solved the footer. But now my nav bar on the actual pages is half way up the page and not sitting at the bottom?

Comment: Is you navbar inside your footer?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
[data-role=page]{
         height: 100% !important; position:relative !important;
}
[data-role=footer]{
         bottom:0; position:absolute !important; top: auto !important; width:100%;
}
```